# What's unusual about the paragraph below?

Tags: cryptography

"This is a highly unusual paragraph. Do you know why? If you try to find what is odd about it too quickly,  it probably won't occur to you. Study it without hurrying and you may think of what it is. Good luck."

It appears as a problem in the exercise of a book I'm reading in the chapter titled "An Application of Statistics -- The Breaking of Ciphers and Codes".

Comment: out of interest - what is the book you are reading?

Comment: Mathematics - A Human Endeavor by Harold R. Jacobs. Copyright 1979.

Comment: @Epictetus It actually from a library in Miramonte High School in the US. I purchased it here in Pakistan in a used book store for something like 25 cents.

Comment: many thanks. I doubt whether it would be available to me for ~25 pence in the UK! :)

Comment: By the way, this sort of thing is known as a [lipogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipogram). The Wikipedia page lists some incredible examples.

Comment: @RahulNarain: I've actually known about this from the novel Gadsby but it wasn't on my mind currently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT: Googl would tll you if you wr to sarch on th obvious.

Comment: I would hav nvr found it.

Comment: If it were written in code, something about the way the paragraph's written would make it difficult to crack...

Comment: @Acid2: How so?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I don't know. If I knew, I wouldn't be asking here. Something tells me you two don't know what's really unusual either.

Comment: @Acid2: There are at least six of us who know. I gave you a huge hint in my answer $-$ the misspellings are there for a reason $-$ and I even told you how you could easily find out. Oh, by the way: it’s not enciphered or encoded. It’s plaintext, but plaintext with a statistically very unusual characteristic that would mildly hamper someone attempting to read a version of it enciphered in a simple substitution cipher.

Comment: Oh! I s now. :)

Comment: AHA now I gt it.

Comment: @Acid2: There you go! :-) (What I searched on was the first sentence of the paragraph.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I tried that before asking here. Didn't find anything relevant. I figured it would be difficult to find anything because the book it comes from is quite old and nobody would've read it recently and have said anything about it on the internet so decided to ask instead. I guess I'm not very good with making Google searches.

Comment: @Acid2: That’s interesting: when I started typing the sentence into Firefox’s search window, Google actually suggested the search *this is a most unusual paragraph riddle*.

Comment: Hm, I knew something of the kind was going on. I started looking for letters hoping that one of them is missing. Found an A, a B, a C. Then I got lazy and looked at your answer )

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oh you typed it and followed the suggestions. I opted for the quick and lazy way of copying and pasting the paragraph between inverted commas to get an exact result... there were no exact matches and I just gave up!